# VBA Returns Incorrect Recordset

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I have a VBA macro which concatenates results where there are multiple results in a day. It retrieves data from an excel spreadsheet as an ADODB.Recordset. The macro finds rows to manipulate and populates values in a new column starting with 1 and increments up as needed.

```
    Set preprocessRng = Range(Cells(2, 28), Cells(30093, 28))

    For i = 1 To 98
        resultConCat = ""
        sql = "SELECT [Result] FROM [output$A1:BA30093] WHERE PreProcess = CInt(" & i & ");"

        rs.Open sql, dbs, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
        With rs
            If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
                .MoveLast
                .MoveFirst

                While (Not .EOF)
                    If resultConCat = "" Then
                        resultConCat = rs.Fields(0).Value
                    Else
                        resultConCat = resultConCat & " / " & rs.Fields(0).Value
                    End If
                    .MoveNext
                Wend

                Set firstCell = preprocessRng.Find(CInt(i))
                Set aCell = preprocessRng.Find(CInt(i))

                Do While Not aCell Is Nothing
                    Cells(aCell.Row, 27).Value = CStr(resultConCat)
                    Set aCell = preprocessRng.FindNext(After:=aCell)
                    If aCell.Address = firstCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Loop

            End If
        .Close
        End With
    Next i
```

The problem is that there are results where PreProcess = 1, but this query returns 0 rows. When sql = where PreProcess = 2, the result set returned is where PreProcess is actually = 1. This pattern continues until PreProcess = 60 where the recordset returned is actually where PreProcess = 59 and 60. Then from 61 on, the correct recordset is returned.

[Actual Results Vs. Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TfOx.png)

If the macro is rerun with the same dataset, the problems are not present.
I have since resolved this problem by starting PreProcess at 100 and incrementing up from there.

```
    Set preprocessRng = Range(Cells(2, 28), Cells(30093, 28))

    For i = 1 To 98
        resultConCat = ""
        sql = "SELECT [Result] FROM [output$A1:BA30093] WHERE PreProcess = CInt(" & i + 100 & ");" 'modified

        rs.Open sql, dbs, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
        With rs
            If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
                .MoveLast
                .MoveFirst

                While (Not .EOF)
                    If resultConCat = "" Then
                        resultConCat = rs.Fields(0).Value
                    Else
                        resultConCat = resultConCat & " / " & rs.Fields(0).Value
                    End If
                    .MoveNext
                Wend

                Set firstCell = preprocessRng.Find(CInt(i + 100)) 'modified
                Set aCell = preprocessRng.Find(CInt(i + 100)) 'modified

                Do While Not aCell Is Nothing
                    Cells(aCell.Row, 27).Value = CStr(resultConCat)
                    Set aCell = preprocessRng.FindNext(After:=aCell)
                    If aCell.Address = firstCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Loop

            End If
        .Close
        End With
    Next i
```

I have a workaround, but am still wondering why this occurs? I have googled this exhaustively and have found nothing similar to this problem. Comments and suggestions welcome.

Comment: Don't you want `WHERE CInt(PreProcess) = " & i & ";"`? There's no point in casting `i`, because it's already an integer.

Comment: @Comintern `CInt(" & i & ")` is needed because excel reads this column as a string, otherwise the code errors out with `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`.

Comment: I realize that, but you're building an SQL query that is going to be `CInt(1)`. You need to cast the ***target column***, not the test.

Comment: You need to make sure your PreProcess column contains only numeric data, and that the Excel driver sees it as numeric, which might not happen if it has empty values in the first 10 (100?) rows.  If you can't do that then try`WHERE PreProcess = '" & i & "' "`  (ie. put single quotes around `i`)

Comment: @Tim First 10,000 rows are blank, using single quotes works well.